# configure proxy_http for apache2 with tomcat7 and webapp under debian wheezy

Tags: apache, web-applications, debian, tomcat7, mod-proxy

I have a vServer with debian 7.8 (wheezy), apache2 webserver and tomcat7.

I deployed a webapp with the apache `www.mydomain.com/manager` app into `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/` which runs perfectly under `www.mydomain.com:8080`. It gets linked to my webapp´s welcome page `www.mydomain.com:8080/app/#welcome`.

My apache2 `www.mydomain.com/host-manager` lists only “*localhost*” under host name.

Now I want to connect my apache2 webserver to tomcat7, so that `www.mydomain.com` starts my webapp (like `www.mydomain.com/#welcome`).

Things, i have done so far:

1. enabled proxy_http, which can be found under `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_http.load`
2. my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file looks like

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName www.mydomain.com 
   ServerAlias mydomain.com 
   ProxyRequest Off 
   ProxyPreserveHost On 

     <Proxy*> 
     Order deny,allow 
     Allow from all 
     </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ 
   ProxyPassReserve / http://localhost:8080/

   DocumentRoot /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/ 
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. changed `/etc/hosts` `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.com`
4. my `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml` looks like

   ```
   <Server port=”8005” shutdown=”SHUTDOWN”>
   ... 
   <Connector port=”8080” protocol=”HTTP/1.1”   
     ... 
     redirectPort=”8443”
     proxyPort=”80” 
     proxyName=”www.mydomain.com” />
   ```

What am i missing?

Comment: What is your error message? There is a space missing between `ProxyPassReserve /` and `http://loclhost` ...

Comment: the missing space was a typo, edited it. I dont get any error...when surf to `www.mydomain.com` i get the standard apache2 site, `www.mydomain.com:8080` gives me the standard tomcat site and `www.mydomain.com:8080/app` gives me my webapp-starting-page

Comment: you said, that you see the default apache2 site, just a guess: did you restart apache2 after your modification? without an error message its hard to find an error...

Comment: With standard site i mean all those "it works" sites. i restarted both, apache2 and tomcat...and i found no error log because every service works just fine, but my proxy config must be wrong. Im pretty new to debian and vserver config, so can you tell me if there is any error log for a wrong proxy config?

Answer (score 2):

From your configuration i noted:

- whitespace at `<_Proxy *>` and  `</Proxy_>`
- `DocumentRoot` in combination with proxy configuration, doesn't make sense
- if you plan to redirect to `localhost:8080/app/` you have to configure this (see below)

I have no tomcat7, but i configured nginx: apache (80) --> proxy --> nginx (8080)

With the following configuration a subdirectoy `app` from nginx is displayed at port 80 via apache. I hope this will help to answer your question (just works fine with Debian 8):

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

enable proxy and restart apache:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
service apache2 restart
```

all possible error messages are logged into `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, you should also take a look at your tomcat logfiles.

If you put the configuration in an other file than `000-default.conf` you have to enable the site with `a2ensite <sitename>` so that apache knows that it exists.

Comment: The whitespaces were typos...i had to figure out how to pass xml code to SO/html first.

Comment: your approach does not fix it either, but +1 for the error log config..hard to figure it out, there must be an url-mapping error.